# Kiel oni nomas la paĝojn de prezento de Powerpoint?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ĉu estas bona vorto por la paĝoj kiujn oni montras dum prezento de Powerpoint? En la angla mi nomus ilin *slides*. Se mi kontrolas tion en [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_en.php?vorto=slide), ĝi proponas «lumbildo». Tamen, tio ŝajnas al mi priskribo de la malnova teknologio kie oni metas travideblan plastan folion super lumo kun spegulo por projekcii la bildon. Ĉu tiu vorto daŭre estas la ĝusta kvankam ĝia vortfarado ne plu havas sencon?

Comment: La sveda versio uzas la vorton por *bildo*, sed tio acxas, cxar igxas konfuze kiam oni enmetu foton aux ilustrajxon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ofte la vorto *paĝo* sufiĉas, sed se pli specifa termino estas bezonata, mi ofte aŭdis *lumbildo*. Tiun vorton oni uzas en la Esperanto-interfaco de OpenOffice/LibreOffice.
http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=slide

Answer (score 5):

En iu prezentado en Youtube, la prezentisto uzis la vorton *folio*. Mi ŝatas tiun vorton, ĉar folioj estas plataj, ili ofte estas kun aliaj folioj , kaj kelkfoje lumo povas trairi ilin.

Mi pensas tiun vorton taŭga por prezentoj Powerpoint-aj, sed ne taŭgaj por prezentoj Prezi-aj (kie estas nur vidpunktoj sur la sama bildo).

Sed pli simple, vi povus uzi la vorton *paĝo*. Ĉiu "slide" fakte estas paĝo post printado.